# Title hover - change image

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have an image with a title above it. I want to display a different image when I hover over the title.

How do I create that?

[title code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJWQi.png)

[image code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSXLW.png)

Guess i gotta put something on the question marks, but what?

Comment: How is the image included, in a  img tag or as the background for the title?

Comment: In an img tag. The image is under the title, but not as a background

Comment: please share some HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $("img")
        .mouseover(function() { 
            $(this).attr("src", "newImage.jpg");
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "originalImage.jpg");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modified version of above jquery or just css.
Give an id for the image and use the id in the jquery code posted by @Sandwell

If you are using css try :hover property

Comment: what do I put on the :hover property

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But if it helps any one else, let me explain. We can achieve this by writing something like below
```<div id="my-img>
</div>


css
#my-mg {
background: url('first-img.jpg')
}

#my-mg:hover {
background: url('second-img.jpg')
}```